# Virtualisation of ubuntu on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualization

I have a computer with windows 7 and can build a windows 7 virtual machine. I am now trying to run ubuntu on this computer. I can't find any 64 bits vmx file for ubuntu.

I've tried to find a downloadable vmx file using google, i only find 32 bits ubuntu files and or only easily accessible from linux.

Do you know an easy way to do this ?
Will the ubuntu vmx file work like windows 7 vmx file ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and cleanest way to setup Ubuntu in a virtual machine is to download the [Ubuntu ISO files](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/), and use VirtualBox to create a new machine.  This ensures a clean installation, and is much, much smaller than an VMX download.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do that. It is for a professional computer so I may not be able to download and install Virtualbox. What would you do with the vmx constraint ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question?  If you're unable to det VirtualBox the point is moot - having a vmx or the ISO will do you no good.

Comment: I have VMware preinstalled, this information seems to be missing in my post.